# Segmentation fault in g++ without -o option

Tags: c++, compiler-construction

When I compile my program without the `g++ -o` options, it fails with the following errors:
None of the symbols it is complaining about is in my program. Why would it compile well with `-o` option, but fail to compile without that option?

```
    integer: In function `_start':
(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `_start'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 0 has invalid symbol index 11
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 1 has invalid symbol index 12
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 2 has invalid symbol index 2
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 3 has invalid symbol index 2
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 4 has invalid symbol index 11
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 5 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 6 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 7 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 8 has invalid symbol index 2
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 9 has invalid symbol index 2
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 10 has invalid symbol index 12
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 11 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 12 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 13 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 14 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 15 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 16 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 17 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 18 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 19 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 20 has invalid symbol index 20
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/crt1.o(.debug_line): relocation 0 has invalid symbol index 2
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.3/../../../../lib/crt1.o:/build/buildd/eglibc-2.11.1/csu/../sysdeps/x86_64/elf/start.S:109: first defined here
integer: In function `_fini':
(.fini+0x0): multiple definition of `_fini'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.3/../../../../lib/crti.o:(.fini+0x0): first defined here
integer:(.rodata+0x0): multiple definition of `_IO_stdin_used'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.3/../../../../lib/crt1.o:(.rodata.cst4+0x0): first defined here
integer: In function `__data_start':
(.data+0x0): multiple definition of `__data_start'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.3/../../../../lib/crt1.o:(.data+0x0): first defined here
integer: In function `__data_start':
(.data+0x8): multiple definition of `__dso_handle'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.3/crtbegin.o:(.data+0x0): first defined here
integer: In function `_init':
(.init+0x0): multiple definition of `_init'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.3/../../../../lib/crti.o:(.init+0x0): first defined here
/tmp/ccWZQo46.o: In function `main':
/home/imarembo/source/zaffire1/integer.cc:839: multiple definition of `main'
integer:(.text+0xe4): first defined here
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.3/crtend.o:(.dtors+0x0): multiple definition of `__DTOR_END__'
integer:(.dtors+0x8): first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: warning: Cannot create .eh_frame_hdr section, --eh-frame-hdr ignored.
/usr/bin/ld: error in integer(.eh_frame); no .eh_frame_hdr table will be created.
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Is there an explanation? Am I missing something here?

Using g++ (Ubuntu 4.4.3-4ubuntu5.1) 4.4.3

<sub>Thanks</sub>

Comment: `-o` as in output? Post your command line.

Comment: you obviously didn't tell the whole truth, what else do you specify besides `-o` which makes the difference?

Comment: g++ -o integer integer.cc (which compiles fine) but when i do g++ -g integer integer.cc (or g++ integer integer.cc) it fails

Comment: where is the _segmentation fault_?

Answer (score 9):

`-o` expects a parameter (output file), you cannot simply remove just the `-o` part.

`g++ -g integer integer.cc` tries to compile `integer.cc` and then link it with the already existing executable (`integer`). It's no surprise you have symbol collisions.

The correct command is: `g++ -g integer.cc` or `` `g++ integer.cc ``